# Is it true that $ \int_{\mathbb R} f(t)g(t) \, dt = \int_{\mathbb R} f'(t) \, dg(t) $?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, bounded-variation, stieltjes-integral

Assume that $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ is a $C^\infty$ function. Further assume that $g$ is continuous and of bounded variation.

Is it true that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f(t)g(t) \, dt = \int_{\mathbb R} f'(t) \, dg(t)
$$
where the left-hand side is a Riemann integral and the right-hand side is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

Comment: No. Take $f(t)\equiv 1$.

Comment: I think there should be an error in displaying the formula. The integration by parts says that the integration of f'g is the integration of fg' plus the difference of the values of fg. I believe you want to say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your equality is not true. We have only such equality
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f(t)g'(t) \, dt = \int_{\mathbb R} f(t) \, dg(t)
$$ which is similar to yours and of course it is known from definition of Riemann-Stieltjes integral.